# Cross Domain Ajax get Request

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain

I'd like to ask a question for cross-domain Get request via Ajax.
My ajax request is Like that

```
var currency_path="http://forex.cbm.gov.mm/api/latest";

$.ajax({  
    url: currency_path,  
    crossDomain:true,  
    type:"GET",  
    dataType:'jsonp',  
    async:false,  
    success: function(data){  
        console.log(data);  
 },  
error: function(){  
     alert('failure');  
}  
}).done(function(msg) {  
    console.log(msg);             
});
```

I got the response but i can't trace that
Any Suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

Look in your JavaScript error console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

You have `dataType:'jsonp',` but the URL is returning JSON.

You can't parse JSON as JSONP, there are different data formats.

Use some other technique to access the data.

Comment: Yes If i change it to json it cannot be access, So how could i do

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy