# Why does my JSONP request give me Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < (less than)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Following is my xmlfile

```
applica.luminoustec.net/file.xml
```

I need to access with this ajax call from my local host, all about is cross domain call

**My AJAX CODE**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $.ajax({
                url: "http://applica.luminoustec.net/file.xml",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

following is the error

**`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`**

can anyone tell where i am at fault

i see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25636932/cross-domain-ajax-get-request)
 and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26497674/cross-domain-jquery-get-request)

but not succeded please help me out

Comment: You'll have to make up your mind—XML or JSONP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`http://applica.luminoustec.net/file.xml` is XML.

`dataType: "jsonp",` tells jQuery to parse it as JSONP.

XML is not JSONP. Thus, it errors.

Either:

1. Change the URL to one which returns [JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about) *or*
2. Remove the `dataType` line and let jQuery detect it as XML (NB: This will probably require that you set up [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) support on the server).

Comment: I attempt with 2 option , now error is

 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://applica.luminoustec.net/file.xml. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:22791' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: @jot yes, that is a CORS error. You have to set up CORS to do #2.

Comment: how to manage with that any idea or helpful link @GeorgeStocker

Comment: @Jot instructions for setting up CORS on various server environments http://enable-cors.org/server.html ... I think you'll want http://enable-cors.org/server_aspnet.html

Comment: @Jot — There's a link in the answer.

Comment: can i do this CORS adding in the plan asp.net or i have to choose asp.net MVC

Comment: if you have a relevent link that can help quicker please provide me

Comment: any example to do so please

Comment: @Jot Setting it up in ASP.NET MVC for development is covered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290053/setting-access-control-allow-origin-in-asp-net-mvc-simplest-possible-method